# What software should I install for opening .stl files?

Tags: 12.10, software-recommendation, file-format

I use Ubuntu 12.10. What software can I install that can open Physible `.stl` files? And what are the differences between these softwares?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) reads all kind of 3D meshes, also STL

```
sudo apt-get install meshlab
meshlab file.stl
```

Example with [this file](https://github.com/brianchowlab/OSP/tree/9b7ebd84fce793ce0b962b4a1db210ce971afb0f/Hardware/CAD%20Files/P1%20-%20X-Axis%20Motor%20Holder):

[image]

Comment: Just a warning: meshlab is terrible for doing any per vertex or per surface rendering. I.e. you can't easily select faces and move them around.

Answer (score 9):

Blender is the best, just import the file.

Comment: To clarify: `apt install blender`, run it, select File→Import→Stl… and navigate to the directory with the `*.stl` files. (It's apparently not possible to paste the path into the File dialogue. ☹)

Answer (score 6):

From OpenSCAD's online User Manual

[STL Import](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/STL_Import) - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/STL_Import

```
import_stl("filename.stl", convexity = <val>)
```

As of version 2019.01, if you do from the command line:

```
openscad file.stdl
```

it automatically opens the GUI with the right command to view the file e.g.:

```
import("/home/ciro/git/OSP/Hardware/CAD Files/P1 - X-Axis Motor Holder/P1 - X-Axis Motor Holder.STL");
```

Then you can click Design > Render, and it gives for [this sample file](https://github.com/brianchowlab/OSP/tree/9b7ebd84fce793ce0b962b4a1db210ce971afb0f/Hardware/CAD%20Files/P1%20-%20X-Axis%20Motor%20Holder):

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to work very well. And technically, that doesn't let you edit the STL file. It just converts the STL file to OpenSCAD's internal format using raytracing, which takes forever.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [F3D](https://github.com/f3d-app/f3d) for this task.

```
f3d yourFile.stl
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/). It is free and is available for Ubuntu.

Comment: but it couldn't open the .stl file i had..

Comment: That's strange. The site says it opens and create stl files. Are you sure you're file is not damaged in some way?

Comment: yes i am absolutely sure my file is fine.

Comment: Very odd, my friend. I will make some research and return if I find a solution.

Comment: It won't open .stl files indeed.

Comment: It might be a newer feature. The current version is 2014.03, but the version in the repo is 2013.02.28.

Comment: I think it is only meant to  export to STL files, it is not a mesh viewer. At least, that is what my 5 minutes of tinkering with an scad file from thingiverse taught me. I used meshlab to view STL files exported from scad.

Comment: you can import STL files using the `import` function: `import("file.stl", convexity=3);`. You will then be able to see the model in the preview window.

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenSCAD version 2015.03-1, it should work also to import .stl files. Please use a command like this:

```
import("/home/documents/Screw.stl", convexity=3);
```

and push the preview button, as suggested by Hall above.

This should work!

To edit the .stl as an object in OpenSCAD, create a module like:

```
module Screw(){
      import("/home/documents/Screw.stl", convexity=3);
}
```

Now you are able to recall it with `Screw()` for further actions.

Answer (score 1):

FreeCAD https://www.freecadweb.org/ also can import *.stl files

Answer (score -2):

I use ChiTuBox on Ubuntu 18.04 (I know you were asking about 12.04 but that was 6 years ago!).

https://www.chitubox.com/download.html